# Is the supply chest on my homestead safe?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-hearthfire

It's been fairly common knowledge that the only guaranteed safe storage containers are those which are inside houses that you own.  However, Hearthfire adds storage containers that are both technically outside and also still your own property.

Are these containers safe to use?  Does it depend on whether or not you've actually gotten to build a house on the property yet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any container **INSIDE** your house is guaranteed safe. On the other hand, containers **OUTSIDE** the house (i.e. barrels, food bags etc) is NOT guaranteed safe. This also applied to any house that isn't yours, although you can sleep in it (i.e. [Alchemist's Shack](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Alchemist%27s_Shack)). Exception for Hearthfire, those containers outside your house are **safe storages** so don't worry about losing anything.

My rule of thumb for safe container is if the container don't respawn items over time, it is a safe container (although this will take some time).

Comment: If I've read the details right, the short answer to my question appears to be "Yes" - correct?

Comment: Yes. Sorry for the long answer LOL. [More info](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/615803-/64044608).

Comment: No worries.  The added detail is appreciated.  It just took a bit of reading and interpretation to pull the answer for my specific case from them.

Answer (score 0):

I constructed a safe in my bedroom for my hearthfire home. Checking the container in the console, it shows the container is set to respawn. Sure enough, the contents are gone after a respawn (except for sapphire claw...)

Chests and wardrobes are safe, but the safe is not. Safe.

It respawns with a little gold and jewels for you.